# Windows phone7 application deployment on phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone, windows-phone-store

I want to install manually downloaded files from marketplace onto my windows phone 7,which do not have SD card. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't install manually downloaded XAP from the Windows Phone marketplace. This xap is encrypted and can be used only on Windows Phone device with SD card. Only marketplace on WP device can read sd card and will be able install apps from it. 
There is no additional tools available that will allow you to install this xap.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is once you obtain the .XAP file which is the WP file format for apps, you can get the Windows Phone SDK which comes with all the Windows Phone developing tools and Application Deployment tool. This allows you to deploy any .XAP file onto your phone.

**Getting the SDK is the only way as I'm not aware if the Application Deployment Tool comes standalone.**

You can get the SDK Here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-nz/download/details.aspx?id=27570

Comment: Where did you get your XAP from? there is a possibility that it could be corrupted? What you can do is get a XAP file which is sure to work and see if it properly works also have you registered and developer unlocked your device?

Comment: I have got that from Marketplace (download and install manually option)

Comment: @NitishBangad You won't be able to install this .xap with Application Deployment Tool that comes with SDK - I've just tested it, you get the error "Xap file is invalid".